# How To Create Custom TextField Class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a custom textfield class so that i can easily change how it looks by only editing in one place. Currently i am facing a problem on how to make a toggle password visibility.

This is what my custom textfield class:

```
class CustomTextFieldOutline extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomTextFieldOutline(
      {this.label,
        this.controller,
        this.isValid,
        this.invalidMsg});

  final String label;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool isValid;
  final String invalidMsg;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: label,
          errorText: isValid ? null : invalidMsg,
          errorStyle: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
          errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
          ),
          focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
          ),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
          )),
      style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
      controller: controller,
    );
  }
}
```

This is how i call it:

```
final _resetPasswordView = Container(
  child: AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _resetPasswordVisibility ? 1.0 : 0.0,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomTextFieldOutline(
          label: constant.email,
          controller: _emailSignInController,
          isValid: _isEmailValid,
          invalidMsg: _emailValidMsg,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

This how my password textfield looks like. I am not using custome textfield class because i dont know how can i implement toggle password visibility in class:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: constant.password,
      suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _togglePasswordVisibility();
        },
        child: Icon(
          _isHidePassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
          color: constant.colorWhite,
        ),
      ),
      errorText: _isPasswordValid ? null : _passwordValidMsg,
      errorStyle: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
      ),
      focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
      ),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
      ),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorWhite),
      )),
  style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
  obscureText: _isHidePassword,
  controller: _passwordSignUpController,
)
```

How can i incorporate the password textfield functionality in the custom class so that i can use it for password or email textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do like this

```
Widget customTextField(TextInputType textInputType) {
    RegExp pattern = RegExp(
        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+");
    TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    if (textInputType == TextInputType.visiblePassword) {
      return TextField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
        obscureText: true,
      );
    } else {
      return TextField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(pattern)],
      );
    }
  }
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            customTextField(TextInputType.visiblePassword),
            customTextField(TextInputType.emailAddress),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

idk how to make RegExp for email, but the results will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample from [instaflutter](https://github.com/instaflutter/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login)

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hint;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Color baseColor;
  final Color borderColor;
  final Color errorColor;
  final TextInputType inputType;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onChanged;

  CustomTextField(
      {this.hint,
      this.controller,
      this.onChanged,
      this.baseColor,
      this.borderColor,
      this.errorColor,
      this.inputType = TextInputType.text,
      this.obscureText = false,
      this.validator});

  _CustomTextFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  Color currentColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentColor = widget.borderColor;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 0.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: currentColor, width: 2.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        child: TextField(
          obscureText: widget.obscureText,
          onChanged: (text) {
            if (widget.onChanged != null) {
              widget.onChanged(text);
            }
            setState(() {
              if (!widget.validator(text) || text.length == 0) {
                currentColor = widget.errorColor;
              } else {
                currentColor = widget.baseColor;
              }
            });
          }, 
          //keyboardType: widget.inputType,
          controller: widget.controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: widget.baseColor,
              fontFamily: "OpenSans",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: widget.hint,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then you can create your widgets

```
 _emailField = new CustomTextField(
      baseColor: Colors.grey,
      borderColor: Colors.grey[400],
      errorColor: Colors.red,
      controller: _email,
      hint: "E-mail Adress",
      inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: Validator.validateEmail,
    );
    _passwordField = CustomTextField(
      baseColor: Colors.grey,
      borderColor: Colors.grey[400],
      errorColor: Colors.red,
      controller: _password,
      obscureText: true,
      hint: "Password",
      validator: Validator.validatePassword,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomTextFieldOutline extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextFieldOutline(
      {Key key, this.hintText, this.label, this.onChange})
      : super(key: key);

  final String hintText;
  final String label;
  final void Function(String value) onChange;

  @override
  _CustomTextFieldOutlineState createState() => _CustomTextFieldOutlineState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldOutlineState extends State<CustomTextFieldOutline> {
  bool showPassword = false;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  void _onChange(String value) {
    controller.text = value;
    if (widget.onChange != null) {
      widget.onChange(value);
    }
  }

  void _changePwdType() {
    setState(() {
      showPassword = !showPassword;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      obscureText: showPassword,
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: (value) => _onChange,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(showPassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
          onPressed: _changePwdType,
        ),
        hintText: widget.hintText != null ? widget.hintText : null,
        labelText: widget.label != null ? widget.label : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implement `OutlineTextFormField` Widget for Custom TextField of my company. I suppose it's pretty easy to extend, and it's include many utilities inside.

**
First, create `outline_text_form_field.dart`:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

const int _defaultMinLinesOnMultiline = 6;

class OutlineTextFormField extends FormField<String> {
  /// Creates a [FormField] that contains a [TextField].
  ///
  /// When a [controller] is specified, [initialValue] must be null (the
  /// default). If [controller] is null, then a [TextEditingController]
  /// will be constructed automatically and its `text` will be initialized
  /// to [initialValue] or the empty string.
  ///
  /// For documentation about the various parameters, see the [TextField] class
  /// and [new TextField], the constructor.
  OutlineTextFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
    bool updateStateIfInternalDataChanged = false,
    this.controller,
    String? initialValue,
    FocusNode? focusNode,
    InputDecoration? decoration,
    String? hintText,
    TextInputType? keyboardType,
    TextCapitalization textCapitalization = TextCapitalization.none,
    TextInputAction? textInputAction,
    TextStyle? style,
    StrutStyle? strutStyle,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    TextAlign textAlign = TextAlign.start,
    TextAlignVertical? textAlignVertical,
    bool autofocus = false,
    bool readOnly = false,
    ToolbarOptions? toolbarOptions,
    bool? showCursor,
    String obscuringCharacter = '•',
    bool obscureText = false,
    bool autocorrect = true,
    bool autoTrimWhenTyping = false,
    SmartDashesType? smartDashesType,
    SmartQuotesType? smartQuotesType,
    bool enableSuggestions = true,
    MaxLengthEnforcement? maxLengthEnforcement,
    int maxLines = 1,
    int? minLines, // when multiline = true, minLines = 6
    bool expands = false,
    int? maxLength,
    bool multiline = false,
    ValueChanged<String>? onChanged,
    GestureTapCallback? onTap,
    VoidCallback? onEditingComplete,
    ValueChanged<String>? onFieldSubmitted,
    FormFieldSetter<String>? onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<String>? validator,
    List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters,
    bool? enabled,
    double cursorWidth = 2.0,
    double? cursorHeight,
    Radius? cursorRadius,
    Color? cursorColor,
    Brightness? keyboardAppearance,
    EdgeInsets scrollPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    bool enableInteractiveSelection = true,
    TextSelectionControls? selectionControls,
    InputCounterWidgetBuilder? buildCounter,
    ScrollPhysics? scrollPhysics,
    Iterable<String>? autofillHints,
    AutovalidateMode? autovalidateMode,
    ScrollController? scrollController,
  })  : assert(initialValue == null || controller == null),
        assert(obscuringCharacter.length == 1),
        assert(
          maxLengthEnforcement == null,
          'maxLengthEnforced is deprecated, use only maxLengthEnforcement',
        ),
        assert(
          (minLines == null) || (maxLines >= minLines),
          "minLines can't be greater than maxLines",
        ),
        assert(
          !expands || minLines == null,
          'minLines and maxLines must be null when expands is true.',
        ),
        assert(!obscureText || maxLines == 1,
            'Obscured fields cannot be multiline.'),
        assert(maxLength == null || maxLength > 0),
        super(
          key: key,
          initialValue: controller != null ? controller.text : initialValue,
          onSaved: onSaved,
          validator: validator,
          enabled: enabled ?? decoration?.enabled ?? true,
          autovalidateMode: autovalidateMode ??
              (validator != null ? AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction : null),
          builder: (FormFieldState<String> field) {
            if (updateStateIfInternalDataChanged &&
                field.value != data) {
              WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                field.didChange(data);
              });
            }

            final _OutlineTextFormFieldState state =
                field as _OutlineTextFormFieldState;
            final InputDecoration effectiveDecoration = InputDecoration(
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              hintMaxLines: 2,
              errorMaxLines: 2,
              helperMaxLines: 2,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 20,
                vertical: 10,
              ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
            ).copyWith(hintText: hintText);
            // .applyDefaults(Theme.of(field.context).inputDecorationTheme);
            void onChangedHandler(String value) {
              field.didChange(autoTrimWhenTyping ? value.trim() : value);

              if (onChanged != null) {
                onChanged(value);
              }
            }

            return TextField(
              controller: state._effectiveController,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              decoration:
                  effectiveDecoration.copyWith(errorText: field.errorText),
              keyboardType: keyboardType,
              textInputAction: textInputAction,
              style: style ?? TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              strutStyle: strutStyle,
              textAlign: textAlign,
              textAlignVertical: textAlignVertical,
              textDirection: textDirection,
              textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
              autofocus: autofocus,
              toolbarOptions: toolbarOptions,
              readOnly: readOnly,
              showCursor: showCursor,
              obscuringCharacter: obscuringCharacter,
              obscureText: obscureText,
              autocorrect: autocorrect,
              smartDashesType: smartDashesType ??
                  (obscureText
                      ? SmartDashesType.disabled
                      : SmartDashesType.enabled),
              smartQuotesType: smartQuotesType ??
                  (obscureText
                      ? SmartQuotesType.disabled
                      : SmartQuotesType.enabled),
              enableSuggestions: enableSuggestions,
              maxLengthEnforcement: maxLengthEnforcement,
              maxLines: multiline ? null : maxLines,
              minLines: minLines == null && multiline
                  ? _defaultMinLinesOnMultiline
                  : minLines,
              expands: expands,
              maxLength: maxLength,
              onChanged: onChangedHandler,
              onTap: onTap,
              onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
              onSubmitted: onFieldSubmitted,
              inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
              enabled: enabled ?? decoration?.enabled ?? true,
              cursorWidth: cursorWidth,
              cursorHeight: cursorHeight,
              cursorRadius: cursorRadius,
              cursorColor: cursorColor,
              scrollPadding: scrollPadding,
              scrollPhysics: scrollPhysics,
              keyboardAppearance: keyboardAppearance,
              enableInteractiveSelection: enableInteractiveSelection,
              selectionControls: selectionControls,
              buildCounter: buildCounter,
              autofillHints: autofillHints,
              scrollController: scrollController,
            );
          },
        );

  /// Controls the text being edited.
  ///
  /// If null, this widget will create its own [TextEditingController] and
  /// initialize its [TextEditingController.text] with [initialValue].
  final TextEditingController? controller;

  late String data;

  @override
  _OutlineTextFormFieldState createState() => _OutlineTextFormFieldState();
}

class _OutlineTextFormFieldState extends FormFieldState<String> {
  TextEditingController? _controller;

  TextEditingController get _effectiveController =>
      widget.controller ?? _controller!;

  late StreamSubscription<String> dataStreamSubscription;

  @override
  OutlineTextFormField get widget => super.widget as OutlineTextFormField;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.controller == null) {
      _controller =
          TextEditingController(text: widget.initialValue ?? widget.data);
    }
    setValue(widget.initialValue ?? widget.data);
    _effectiveController.addListener(_handleControllerChanged);
    dataStreamSubscription = Stream.value(widget.data).listen(_onData);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(OutlineTextFormField oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.controller != oldWidget.controller) {
      oldWidget.controller?.removeListener(_handleControllerChanged);
      widget.controller?.addListener(_handleControllerChanged);

      if (oldWidget.controller != null && widget.controller == null)
        _controller =
            TextEditingController.fromValue(oldWidget.controller!.value);
      if (widget.controller != null) {
        setValue(widget.controller!.text);
        if (oldWidget.controller == null) _controller = null;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    dataStreamSubscription.cancel();
    _effectiveController.removeListener(_handleControllerChanged);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChange(String? value) {
    super.didChange(value);

    if (_effectiveController.text != value) {
      _effectiveController.text = value ?? '';
      _effectiveController.selection =
          TextSelection.collapsed(offset: value?.length ?? 0);
    }
    widget.data = _effectiveController.text;
  }

  @override
  void reset() {
    // setState will be called in the superclass, so even though state is being
    // manipulated, no setState call is needed here.
    _effectiveController.text = widget.initialValue ?? widget.data;
    super.reset();
  }

  void _handleControllerChanged() {
    // Suppress changes that originated from within this class.
    //
    // In the case where a controller has been passed in to this widget, we
    // register this change listener. In these cases, we'll also receive change
    // notifications for changes originating from within this class -- for
    // example, the reset() method. In such cases, the FormField value will
    // already have been set.
    if (_effectiveController.text != value)
      didChange(_effectiveController.text);
  }

  void _onData(String value) {
    if (_effectiveController.text != value) _effectiveController.text = value;
  }
}
```

** After you can use it:

```
String? validateStringBlank(
            String? value,
            String msg, [
            bool autoToLowerCase = true,
          ]) =>
              (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty)
                  ? "Vui lòng nhập ${autoToLowerCase ? msg.toLowerCase() : msg}"
                  : null;

 

OutlineTextFormField(
            data: "Apple",
            hintText: "Enter company name",
            validator: (value) =>
                validateStringBlank(value,"Company Name"),
          ),
```